# human stripes animation inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/yKvuK/

as you can see when the human walk the image remain in it's place can i change the code so when i press left the image change it's position and look like it's walking to the left and not just walk in place ?

```
            function update() {
            canvas.clearRect(0, 0, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);
            if (keydown.left) {
                    CurentPos++;
                    if (CurentPos == ImgNumb) {
                        CurentPos = 0;
                    }
            }
        } // end update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yKvuK/1/

Basically, each time you change the frame, the "`left`" variable is decremented, so he moves left.

```
 // I draw the "init" picture at x=250, so he has more space to walk.

 var left = 250;

 function update() {
     canvas.clearRect(0, 0, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);
     if (keydown.left) {
         CurentPos++;
         if (CurentPos == ImgNumb) {
             CurentPos = 0;
         }
         left -= 5; // <----
     }
 } // end update

 ...
 ...


 function draw() {
     canvas.drawImage(characterImg, CurentPos * 64, 0, 64, 64, left, 200, 64, 64);
 }
```

---

btw, I've never seen /worked with a canvas. Looks like I was just lucky to pick the right variable :P

Comment: Bah! Beat me to it. FYI there is already `x` and `y` variables declared for this purpose, so you could use those. Here's the fiddle I amended: http://jsfiddle.net/yKvuK/3/

Comment: Oh you're right! I didn't notice the variable, since it was nowhere used... Certainly better than declaring yet another.

Comment: i have edited my jsfiddle and now the character can walk to the right as well but there is a problem with flipping the image so he would look like walking right plz can u help : http://jsfiddle.net/yKvuK/5/

Comment: You are flipping the entire canvas, that wont work. You will need two images of the monkey, one left, one right (perhaps make the right one by flipping the left one at the beginning). Then you just select which image to use, based on last movement direction (store that in a var in the keydown function: -1 left, 1 right)

Answer (score 1):

This will work: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3ruu/1/)**

Use your `x` variable (instead of adding new) and you will be able to use it on the move-right movement also. Add it in `update()`.

```
if (keydown.left) {
    CurentPos++;
    x -= 3;  // I used 3 but increase this to move faster
    if (CurentPos == ImgNumb) {
         CurentPos = 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
canvas.drawImage(characterImg, CurentPos * 64, 0, 64, 64, 200 + x, 200, 64, 64);
```

Comment: i have edited my jsfiddle and now the character can walk to the right as well but there is a problem with flipping the image so he would look like walking right plz can u help : http://jsfiddle.net/yKvuK/5/